# Elabore una plantilla html para enviar correos pero al momento de recibir por correo esos correos no me aparecen los iconos que agregue con google

Tags: html5

[image: imagen de como se aprecia el icono]

Importe de la siguiente manera el icono por medio del los iconos que proporciona google

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Alerta Por Activarse</title>
  </head>
  
<i
                    class="material-icons"
                    style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold"
                    >launch</i
                  >
```